# Mismatched type on "this" in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

Im trying to get data from an api, and im running into an error on this line
`val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)`
The error says "Type mismatch: inferred type is Home but Context! was expected"
I have tried changing "this" to "this@MainActivity", However this just made Main Activity go red and when i hover over it, it says unresolved reference
My whole code is below, thanks for any help in advance

```
package com.example.temperaturesensor

import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONTokener

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [Home.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class Home : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
        val url = "https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/alex9301/feeds/test-data/data" // Your URL
        var urlStuff = ""
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                urlStuff = response
                val jsonArray = JSONTokener(urlStuff).nextValue() as JSONArray
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    // ID
                    val id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("value") // Get data
                    Log.i("Val: ", id)

                }
            },
            { Log.i("b", "That didn't work!") })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Home.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Home().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: this replace to this@YourActivityName

Comment: So I try to change this to val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity), but MainActivity is just red

Comment: send this full code

Comment: I have edited the post to include the whole code

Comment: bro this fragment not activity

Comment: just minute i sent you

Comment: my code copy paste your screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.example.temperaturesensor

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONTokener

class Home : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(view.context)
        val url = "https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/alex9301/feeds/test-data/data" // Your URL
        var urlStuff = ""
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                urlStuff = response
                val jsonArray = JSONTokener(urlStuff).nextValue() as JSONArray
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    // ID
                    val id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("value") // Get data
                    Log.i("Val: ", id)

                }
            },
            { Log.i("b", "That didn't work!") })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
        return view
    }


}
```

Comment: please correct symbol click

Answer (score 1):

use requireContext() because you are in a fragment not an Activity